# When to use jmap -J<flag> option?

Tags: java, jmap

I am going through jmap command documentation. -J options is documented like below.

```
-J<flag> : to pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
```

I am not getting, where exactly this scenario helps. For the experiment sake, I tried to increase the heap size of the running applicaiton using below command.

```
jmap -J-Xmx1024m <PROCESS_ID>
```

But there is no change in the heap size. I would like to know the use cases of jmap -J option. Please help me in understanding -J option.

Comment: Try removing the hyphen after the J.

Comment: Also Xss changes the stack size.

Comment: I executed the statement 'jmap -JXss2m <PID>, but i got 
"Error: Could not find or load main class Xss2m"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the runtime system the documentation is referring to is the Java process that the `jmap` command is running in - it too is written in Java.

`-J` works OK in `jmap` - e.g. one way to check this is to reduce the memory too far:

```
C:\>jmap -J-Xmx1m -histo <pid>
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size
```

As for increasing the heap size of a running Java process, I'm not aware of any option to do this.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718547/is-it-possible-to-increase-a-java-processswhen-is-running-size) largely confirms this.

Most changes you can make to a running JVM would be from a JMX bean in [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html), but [not memory changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713157/can-javas-jconsole-be-used-to-automatically-configure-memory) unfortunately.